# How to use Google API for cloud billing to get information PER node?

Tags: google-api

I can get billing per *service* when I use the SKUs catalog API.

But how can I get per *node* cost through that API?

Comment: Welcome to stack.  Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.  You may want to read this before asking your next question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.